# SPUser.Groups is empty

Tags: spuser, ssom, spgroup

I have an SPUser object generated from the currently logged in user via `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` however `user.Groups` is coming back empty.  I checked the group, the user is in the group.  Just to be sure, I've checked the user's permissions via Site Permissions -> Check Permissions through the GUI.  The user is in multiple groups. I've checked the user object and it is the user I expect.  This is for a FBA user.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be really simple.  There were two FBA users with the same email so I was logged in as the wrong user and had no idea.

Comment: I had the same issue, and seems like one user was added with *claim-based authentication*, while the *duplicate user* was added by `DOMAIN\UserName`. great catch! thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, is the user added directly to a site instead of a SP Group?  Judging by your post I don't think this is the case, but thought I would ask.

I would do some testing from the other side.  Try getting the group in particular that you are sure he is part of and see if he is listed there.

```
var users = SPGroup.Users;
```

If the user is not there, I wonder if there is an issue with your user within UPS.  Does the user belong in an OU that UPS isn't indexing?